# Reply to direct messages of twitter using node.js API in Twitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I am using [twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit) npm package to read direct messages

```
var stream = T.stream('user', { stringify_friend_ids: true })
stream.on('direct_message', function (directMsg) {
console.log(directMsg)
}
```

I want to reply the `directMsg` received , is there any method call of twit which can be used to achieve or any other nodejs package recommended to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't provide the exact code solution, but the way is to implement the following steps

1. Get `USER_ID` property from `directMsg` object
2. Use Twit Rest API method `T.post(path, [params], callback)` to send direct message to the user with `USER_ID`
3. Use [Twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/direct_messages/new) to understand what you need to send direct messages, you need to properly provide parameters like in documentation

> [image]

So the code will look like this

```
T.post("direct_messages/new", {
    user_id: USER_ID, // USER_ID is parameter from directMsg object
    text: 'YOUR_REPLY'
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: i have to add `screen_name: eventMsg.direct_message.recipient_screen_name` to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Even i ran into it, here is what you have to do.
Listen to the `user` stream for `direct_message` and retrieve the `sender.screen_name` and `recipient.screen_name` and verify it's not equal + you need the `sender.id` as stated by @RashadIbrahimov above.

```
  // Reply to Twitter messages
 function replyToDirectMessage(){

  //get the user stream
  var stream = T.stream('user');

stream.on('direct_message', function (eventMsg) {
  var msg = eventMsg.direct_message.text;
  var screenName = eventMsg.direct_message.sender.screen_name;
  var userId = eventMsg.direct_message.sender.id;

  // reply object
  var replyTo = { user_id: userId,
    text: "Thanks for your message :)", 
    screen_name: screenName };

  console.log(screenName + " says: " + msg );

  // avoid replying to yourself when the recipient is you
  if(screenName != eventMsg.direct_message.recipient_screen_name){

    //post reply
    T.post("direct_messages/new",replyTo, function(err,data,response){
            console.info(data);
        });
    }
});
}
```

and call it
`replyToDirectMessage();`